# container for PHP's composer package-manager shows message / error: "docker_composer_1 exited with code 0" with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, composer-php, yaml, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a `composer` container (`Dockerfile`) and use this container in my `docker-compose.yml` but it looks like the container doesn't start.

I'm facing the following message every time I run `docker-compose up`

> docker_composer_1 exited with code 0

These are my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files:

Dockerfile

```
#composer
FROM composer
EXPOSE 9090
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ../src/html:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    volumes:
      - ./database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql

  phpmyadmin:
    build:
      context: ./phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=database
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - database

  composer:
    build:
      context: ./composer
    volumes:
      - ../src/html:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
```

I don't want to install Composer into php container.
I don't see this to be an elegant solution.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: theres a big possibility that port 80 is already used on our local. try changing that?

Comment: What command is the container running?  Can you add its `Dockerfile` to the question?  "Exited with code 0" generally means "it ran to completion successfully".

Comment: @JoshBeauregard doesn't work. I've just tried

Comment: @DavidMaze dockerfile code is listed in the first lines of this code block.

Comment: If you `docker-compose run composer` in isolation, what happens?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran the command and showed me all the composer commands.

Comment: ...and then exited?  That will produce the "exit status 0" you show in the question.

Comment: A container is **not** a virtual machine. Per default it will do a job, then die. MySQL, PHP-FPM and NGINX are "special" containers, because they all run a task in the background so they never die. But a composer command just install, update, or whatever you instruct it and then finishes, which **will** make your container die as it should. So what you are epxeriencing here is the normal behaviour of a docker container.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to expose port 9090 from a container with just composer (a package-manager) inside?

Answer (score 1):

`composer` is a package-manager and - as opposed to a "service" - does **not** run as a never-ending process.

`composer` commands are meant to be run once, perform a task and end with a status-code after they have finished their task (i.e. install or update packages, show package information, ...). This status code is `0` if the command ran successfully and non-zero if it failed.

#### Conclusion:

> The message that the container excited with status code `0` is **not an indication** of failure but the expected behavior of every `composer [..]` command.

When your `composer` container is started, it executes the default command for the container which is configured by `CMD` in a `Dockerfile` and falls back to the `ENTRYPOINT` which is the `composer` executable without any arguments.

You can verify this behavior by running:

```
docker-compose logs composer
```

`composer` is just a utility and as such should not be defined as a "service" in your `docker-compose.yml`. You can leave it in there for the convenience of being able to run quick one-off commands like:

```
docker-compose run composer install
```

... but you'll have to live with the notice that the command has exited.

#### General Advice:

`docker-compose` is not a task-runner and it's not designed for one-off commands. Several proposals to implement features to support such functionality have been rejected by the maintainers.

Example(s):

- implement an option to skip auto-starting of certain containers with `docker-compose up` -> See this [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896)

Comment: Make sense. Thank you for your elaborated answer!!
Could you please tell me how can I run Composer in a php docker container?
I mean, I need to check for example the version on the composer in a docker container. How can I do that? I am asking you this because I need to install laravel and some other packages and, at this moment when I try to run a command I get: "composer not found"